# Can Litecoin & Bitcoin have overlapping Transaction Ids (txid)

Tags: hash, cryptocurrency

Im currently coding my own transaction lookup page for cryptos. Since Litecoin and Bitcoin are so similar to their txid. I wanted to ask if its actually possible that these 2 currencies have overlapping txid's. I know that Bitcoin uses sha256 & Litecoin uses scrypt.

Let me know, im really interested.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about noon cryptographic aspects of a cryptocurrency.

Comment: This is off topic. The related question, "Can SHA-256 and Scrypt with 256-bit digest size collide?" would be on-topic. The answer would be "Yes, with probability equal to the birthday bound, i.e. $2^{-128}$. So in practice this will never happen."